# Найти максимальную длину последовательности бинарного кода, который состоит только из 0

Tags: java

Вот мой код:

```
import java.io.File;

public class BinaryLength {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
    File file =new File("t.dat");

    if(file.exists()){
      double bytes = file.length();

      System.out.println("bytes : " + bytes); }
      else {
       System.out.println("File does not exists!");
    }

    }
}
```

У меня код ищет только длину всех строк. Как найти длину самой длинной последовательности бинарного файла, что состоит с байтов со значением 0.?

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком непонятный чтобы пытаться начать отвечать на него. Переформулируйте содержание вопроса и желаемый результат.

Comment: **только 0** подразумевается что? Что это? Присутствует символ **0**, строка состоящая из символа **0**? Ваш код показывает размер файла. И ему не важно текстовый файл или бинарный.

Comment: Мне важно, чтобы он был именно бинарным. И там подразумевается, что строка состоит из нулей.

Comment: Нули это 0x00 в бинарном виде?

Comment: Да, 0х00 в бинарном виде.

Comment: Почему Вы тогда все время говорите "строка"? Какое отношение ко всему этому имеют строки?

Comment: Я так поняла это задание.

Comment: Так покажите точное задание, а не своё толкование

Comment: Найти длину  самой длинной последовательности бинарного файла, что состоит с байтов со значением 0.

Answer (score 3):

Логика:

Узнать длину файла в целочисленную переменную (`long filelen`)
Если длина приемлемая, прочитать всё содержимое в массив байтов, например:

```
  byte[] data =  Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

Пройти в цикле по `data`, поддерживая состояние "ноль-не ноль" `boolean isZero`
Если происходит переход в состояние "ноль", то запомнить позицию `start`
Если происходит переход в состояние "не ноль", то определить длину серии нулей вычитанием start из текущей позиции, сравнить с максимальной длиной.
То же самое сделать, если файл кончается в состоянии "ноль"

Если длина очень велика (памяти не хватит), то придётся завести буфер в несколько мегабайт, и читать кусками, на забывая склеивать длины нулевых серий через границы сегментов.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Жаль что вопрос так плох ..

Comment: @Kromster Ну человек пока в замешательстве, будем надеяться, что продвинется в понимании задачи и улучшит его.

Comment: В духе SO было бы здорово, если бы вы смогли сами переписать вопрос в приличный вид. Так чтобы он стал частью базы знаний и помогал найти в том числе и ваш ответ.